# What I need to do when I want to change from IEEEtran as bibliography style to acm style?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, acm

I am pretty new to Latex world. I am a beginner, so bear with me, please!

I chose arbitrarily `IEEEtran` as my bibliography style since it looked by then perfect, and now I have just noticed that one of the formal requirements of the homework I am working on is to have the following particular format "surname, multiple initials" for authors' names.

I thought it would be easy since all my references are managed by Bibdesk and contained in `.bib`, so all I'd have to do is to change `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` into `\bibliographystyle{acm}`.

And, surely, I received a list of errors as shown in the pic:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: hard to give definite help with no example code shown, but  the `not style defined` warning means you have entries of the form `@somename` using a non standard name rather than `@article` or `@misc` etc, is your file really called `m23ref.bib.bib` with two extensions? and are your references numeric like `ref:paper20` that would be rather odd?

Comment: so basically just edit the bib file for those three entries to change `@whatever-it-is` to `@article` and make sure they have an `author="someone"` entry, then it should work with no warnings.

Comment: If an entry type isn't style-defined, its type will default to `@misc`, the "catch-all" entry type. By the way, those messages are "just" warnings, *not* errors.

Comment: Please tell us more about the entries with keys `ref:paper19`, `ref:paper20`, and `ref:paper21`. Is it true that they lack fields named `author` and `key`?

Answer (score 1):

They are not errors, but warnings.

```
Warning--entry type for "zzz" isn't style-file defined
```

means that your `bib` file (which seems to have a `.bib.bib` extension?) has 3 entries of the form

```
@something{zzz,
  title={whatever},
  journal={somewwhere},
  pages={1396--1404},
  year={2015},
  publisher={someone}
}
```

where the `@something` is an unknown reference type (you could change it to `@misc` or `@article` or anything else appropriate)

The three entries have no `author=` field, so BibTeX can not sort the entries in order of author name, so you need to give it a `key=...` field just so BibTeX knows how to sort this entry.

You appear to be using citation keys like `\cite{ref:20}` which is legal syntax but a very confusing practice as the number assigned by bibtex will typically not be the number used in the key.